# Solving a common emitter amplifier problem

Tags: electrical-engineering, circuits, electronics

My work is posted along with the question. I received help in office hours and this small signal equivalent was derived. I was told to use the formulas in the pictures to derive the voltage gain and solve for R_B.

However, there seems to be two issues. The first is that both R_L and the source should be connected to ground,and after shorting the DC supplies, R_C and R_B should be connected to ground as well. Right now they are connected to the emitter instead.

The second issue is that I do not have the value for V_B, so I cannot use it to solve for R_B right now.

This problem is difficult because it isn’t exactly a common emitter. A common emitter should have the emitter connected to ground, but the absence of the bypass capacitor means it will not be.

How should I solve for vin and R_B?

[image: question circuit diagram]
[image: work done]

Comment: Welcome. // Sorry, don't want to spend more time to find your question, hidden somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> The first is that both R_L and the source should be connected to ground,and after shorting the DC supplies, R_C and R_B should be connected to ground as well. Right now they are connected to the emitter instead.

After shorting the DC source (there is only one here, which is Vcc), one of the terminals of Rc and Rb will be connected to the ground (the other end will be connected to the emitter).

> The second issue is that I do not have the value for V_B, so I cannot use it to solve for R_B right now.

You can find Vb using KVL on the input side (Ib can be found from B and Icq, and Ie can be approximated with Icq=5mA ).

Ib = Icq/B

Vcc-(Ib* Rb)-Vce-(Ie* Re) = 0

Rb = (Vcc-Vce-(Ie* Re))/Ib

Comment: Ah this makes sense. I think this was the solution that my professor gave me as well. Also, in your KVL eq you use Vce, but I think you meant Vbe, right?